# Owl Curasol Not working in my date picker

Tags: datepicker, owl-carousel

Hi I have Date picker on select Date Month & Year it will show all Date in that Moth it working Fine

Now I want to add a Slider On that so that i used Owl Curasol after adding Curasol Date picker Stopped Working.

**`My Full code`**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Powerful-Customizable-jQuery-Carousel-Slider-OWL-Carousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
var weekday = new Array(7);
        weekday[0] = "Sunday";
        weekday[1] = "Monday";
        weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
        weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
        weekday[4] = "Thursday";
        weekday[5] = "Friday";
        weekday[6] = "Saturday";
$(function() {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        minDate: 0,
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            $d = new Date(inst.selectedYear, parseInt(inst.selectedMonth)+1, 0).getDate();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
            html='';
            for(i=1;i<=$d;i++){
                console.log(inst.selectedYear+'-'+(parseInt(inst.selectedMonth)+1)+'-'+i);
                d = new Date(inst.selectedYear+'-'+(parseInt(inst.selectedMonth)+1)+'-'+i);
                console.log(d);
                n = weekday[d.getDay()];
                html += '<div class="datediv">div-'+i+'<br>'+n+'</div>';
            }
            $('#datecontent').html(html);
        }
    });
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).live('click', '.datediv', function() { alert("hello"); });});
});
</script>
```

**Html Code**

```
<label for="startDate">Date :</label>
    <input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
    <div id="datecontent" id="owl-demo">
    </div>
```

**`Owl Script`**

```
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Powerful-Customizable-jQuery-Carousel-Slider-OWL-Carousel/assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Powerful-Customizable-jQuery-Carousel-Slider-OWL-Carousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
          items : 10, //10 items above 1000px browser width
          itemsDesktop : [1000,5], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
          itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3], // betweem 900px and 601px
          itemsTablet: [600,2], //2 items between 600 and 0;
          itemsMobile : false // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
      });

    });   

</script>
```

I got This error **`TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function`**

How to fix this issue. I think because of Jquery Conflict Only

How to over come on this??

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/nrev8n8h/ your code is working fine.

Comment: Slider not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps!

You should use the `add` method in carousel to append items inside carousel.Also use `refresh` to run the slider after appending.

```
owl.trigger('add.owl.carousel', ['<div class="datediv">div-'+i+'<br>'+n+'</div>']).trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
```

use `remove` method to remove items from carousel before appending new items.

```
for (var i =0; i< $('.owl-item').length; i++) {
owl.trigger('remove.owl.carousel', [i]).trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var weekday = new Array(7);
        weekday[0] = "Sunday";
        weekday[1] = "Monday";
        weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
        weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
        weekday[4] = "Thursday";
        weekday[5] = "Friday";
        weekday[6] = "Saturday";
    $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        minDate: 0,
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            $d = new Date(inst.selectedYear, parseInt(inst.selectedMonth)+1, 0).getDate();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
            for (var i =0; i< $('.owl-item').length; i++) {
owl.trigger('remove.owl.carousel', [i]).trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
}
            for(i=1;i<=$d;i++){
                console.log(inst.selectedYear+'-'+(parseInt(inst.selectedMonth)+1)+'-'+i);
                d = new Date(inst.selectedYear+'-'+(parseInt(inst.selectedMonth)+1)+'-'+i);
                console.log(d);
                n = weekday[d.getDay()];
               owl
    .trigger('add.owl.carousel', ['<div class="datediv">div-'+i+'<br>'+n+'</div>'])
    .trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
            }
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.datediv', function() { alert("hello"); });
    var owl = $(".owl-demo");
  owl.owlCarousel({
          margin: 20,
          items : 10, //10 items above 1000px browser width
          itemsDesktop : [1000,5], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
          itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3], // betweem 900px and 601px
          itemsTablet: [600,2], //2 items between 600 and 0;
          itemsMobile : false // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
      });

  });
```

```css
.owl-item {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.3/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.3/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label for="startDate">Date :</label>
<input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
<div id="datecontent" class="owl-demo">
</div>
```

Comment: If i select Second moth previous month should disable but here all month date appending

Comment: Check ur answer it will show 2 4 6 8 etc... like this